# Why can't you use a USB stick as the storage media for Apple's Time Machine (backup utility)

Tags: backup, usb-drive, apple

Apologies for an Apple specific question.  I'll delete it if someone can point me at a more Apple-specific Exchange site.

Question is: *why doesn't Apple's Time Machine (backup utility) recognize a USB stick as a valid option for the storage media for backups?*

Yes, a USB stick is slower than a hard drive, but I care only that backups are done, not about the speed of doing them.

Comment: Time machine supports external USB disks.  It may be picky about the filesystem on that disk.  Typically a USB stick would be vfat or exfat, and I suspect neither of those work with it.  Also, it needs to be larger than what you are backing up...

Comment: What type of file system exists on your USB drive?

Comment: The more Apple-specific SE site you are looking for is https://apple.stackexchange.com/